# ER diagrams: can two different notations be used in same diagram?

Tags: entity-relationship, database-schema

Within the one ER diagram is it possible to use the 1...* etc type of notation as well as the arrow notations in order to show cardinality constraints or does it have to be either or.

Answer (score 0):

Often CASE tools such as CA ERwin or IBM Data Architect allow to display both relationship type (in IE crow-feet symbols) and also description of cardinality type.

If relationship is potentially one - to - many, it can described as broken crow feet symbol and cardinality type describtion of zero, one or M.